# Extract all words from string except words in square brackets

Tags: regex, matlab

Again I'm totally stuck in creating a regular expression.

I have a string pattern like:

`str = '    wordA   []  wordAB [xyz]     wordABC     [x]  '`

So there is always a word followed by something in brackets `[ ... ]` or empty brackets `[]`. The length of the words, the leading and trailing white spaces and the number of chars inside the brackets is random. Also random is how often this sequence is repeated.

I'd like to extract just the words without brackets:

```
output = 

    'wordA'    'wordBC'    'wordABC'
```

I think the problem are the square brackets as they are functional characters for regular expressions. I tried something like

```
output = regexp(str,'^\[.+\]$','split')
```

and variations without success.

Any hints?

Comment: Only `\[.+?\]` will do.

Comment: @SabujHassan No it does not work, it don't get the last word and they still contain the white spaces. -> `' wordA '    ' wordABC '    ' '`

Comment: hmm... didn't see that you have an empty `[]` in input. `\s*\[.*?\]\s*` :-)

Comment: @SabujHassan feel free to write it as an answer, I can work with your solution. Though I was actually looking for something more elegant, means not using `'split'`, like "match every word except `'\[.*?\]'` which would exclude the "empty word" after the last pair of brackets, which is now also detected.

Comment: How about `(?<=\s|^)\w+(?=\s)`?

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov this one works perfectly! But I have absolutely no idea how it works (though I understood the first suggestion). You may post an answer with some explanations? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can select all words using `\w+` regex. But it would select all words (include those ones in brackets). Words outside of brackets have spaces before and after them, so we can add positive lookbehind `(?<=\s)` - be sure that there is space before the word, and positive lookahead `(?=\s)` - be sure that there is space after the word. Additionally first word doesn't have space before it, so we need to include condition to include *start of string* as well, giving us positive lookbehind `(?<=\s|^)`. Finally we have full regex:

```
(?<=\s|^)\w+(?=\s)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

In case if you can have `wordA[]` string (no spaces), then you need to add `[` to positive lookahead.

```
(?<=\s|^)\w+(?=\s|\[)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

In case if you can have `wordA [ xyz ]` strings (spaces within brackets), the above regex wouldn't work and we need different strategy - find words not having `[` before. But we cannot just say *words without [ before them*, because it would match `yz` in `[xyz]`, we need to say that we need words not leaded by `[` and symbols other than `]`.

```
(?<!\[[^]]*)\w+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: Thank you! the last case won't happen.

Comment: @thewaywewalk Glad to help. Please check third case to be sure that it doesn't happen for you.

Comment: I expected it to may fail for words like `word_2` but even these ones are matching correctly. So there shouldn't be any problems