# Remove "square brackets and characters within it" from the string-- Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a problem removing the text and special characters from the string. For eg:
`str = 'Accleration [ms^{{-}2}]';`

The expected output: `str_out = 'Acceleration';` I tried using the function regexprep but couldn't get the result as expected.

Comment: Which characters should be removed? How can it be identified?

Comment: The text and characters within square brackets and also the square brackets.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403122/regular-expression-to-extract-text-between-square-brackets

Comment: strcat(str(1:findstr('[',str)-1),str(findstr(']',str)+1:end))

Comment: i replaced findstr with strfind and it's working perfectly.

Comment: I thought it's the other way around :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extract all words from string except words in square brackets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23110509/extract-all-words-from-string-except-words-in-square-brackets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
opens = str == '[';
closes = str == ']';
nestingcount = cumsum(opens - [0 closes(1:end-1)]);
outstr = str(nestingcount == 0);
```

Note that trimming trailing spaces was not part of your specification, you'll have to do that as well to get your example to work right.